# Quale devo usare: "la scala" o "le scale"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, vocabulary, nouns, plural

Lo so che alcune parole sono usate solo in forma plurale. Es: "i pantaloni". Ho sempre pensato che questo fosse vero anche per "**le scale**". Ma oggi stavo guardando alcune immagini di architettura e l'ho visto il termine "**la scala** metallica". Poi in alcuni punti l'ho visto anche usato come "le scale metalliche". Ora, non sono sicuro di quale devo usare. Quale è corretto? Scala o scale?

Comment: Da italiano, direi che soprattutto nel parlato, scala/scale tendono ad essere intercambiabili se si sta parlando della parte architettonica di un edificio; non sono sicuro da dove derivi questa consuetudine, forse per il fatto che in un edificio la scala è vista come una specie di nome "collettivo", che riguarda quasi sempre più di un piano (c'è una scala che collega ogni piano e in totale diventano le scale); ufficialmente però si dovrebbe usare il singolare. Se si parla di un oggetto singolo tipo https://images.obi-italia.it/product/IT/1500x1500/391598_1.jpg si usa sempre il singolare.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi:  Perché "ufficialmente però si dovrebbe usare il singolare"? Secondo il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scala): "spesso al plur., l’insieme di più rampe".

Comment: @Charo beh... ho pensato che nei condomini si usa nelle targhe "Scala A" o "Scala 1" intendevo questo per "ufficialmente"... termine un po' infelice lo ammetto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondo il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00756.jpg)] e [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00756.jpg)]), il termine *scala* può avere parecchi significati. Uno è questo:

> Elemento architettonico di un edificio costituito da una successione di gradini disposti secondo un piano inclinato, diviso a volte in più rampe inframmezzate da un pianerottolo; serve a superare un dislivello e a passare da un piano all’altro dell'edificio.

In questo caso, si può usare *scala* al singolare, come in questo esempio di Giuseppe Antonio Borgese

> Feci la scala di tutta corsa come se volessi salire in terrazza, e mi misi lì dritta a guardare tutti quelli che entravano

ma si trova spesso al plurale e allora significa un insieme formato da parecchie rampe:

> – Al plur. Insieme di più rampe.

Ecco un esempio di Guglielmo Massaia:

> Dovendo in quel tempo frequentare i ministeri, e segnatamente quello degli affari
>   stranieri (dove, entrando, mi presentavano le armi), restava meravigliato nel vedere tanti missionari scendere e salire quelle scale.

Un altro significato di *scala* è il seguente:

> Struttura mobile di legno o anche di metallo, composta da una serie di pioli, usati come gradini, incuneati fra due montanti paralleli; si appoggia all'ostacolo verticale che si intende superare e serviva, in passato, come mezzo per scalare le mura
>   di una città o di una fortezza assediata (anche nelle espressioni *Scala a mano*, *a pioli*, *portatile*).

Può anche trattarsi di una *scala a libretto*

> – *Scala a libretto*: quella formata da due montanti uniti da pioli incernierati ad altri due montanti, che le permettono di reggersi autonomamente senza appoggi superiori

o persino di una *scala a corda*

> Attrezzo formato da due funi parallele collegate da staggi di corda o di legno, di uso soprattutto marinaresco.

In questi casi, se si tratta di una singola struttura, si usa il singolare.

Comment: Grazie! Penso di aver capito. Quindi dalla mia comprensione, le seguenti frasi sarebbero vere: **Anche se faceva caldo, salivo le scale per visitare il Parco Güell**, **Perché la mia gamba è rotta non posso usare la scala per andare al secondo piano** e **La scala al supermercato sono talvolta utili per prendere la roba sugli scaffali superiori.**

Comment: @Tamuno nell'ultima frase "La scala al supermercato sono talvolta utili per prendere la roba sugli scaffali superiori" il soggetto è "Le scale" (sono utili...) (plurale), altrimenti sarebbe "La scala al supermercato è talvolta utile".

Comment: Sì, @tamuno, con la correzione fatta da Riccardo De Contardi.

Comment: Ah sì. Ho usato prima "le scale", poi sono tornato a "la scala". Ecco perché ho dimenticato la parte "sono". Grazie a tutti! Ora capisco.

Answer (score 3):

Guardiamo nei “Promessi sposi”.

> Renzo accostò di nuovo l’uscio pian piano; e tutt’e quattro su per le scale, non facendo rumore neppur per uno. Giunti sul pianerottolo, i due fratelli s’avvicinarono all’uscio della stanza, ch’era di fianco alla scala; gli sposi si strinsero al muro.

Siamo nella famosa *notte degli inganni*, il capitolo 8 che comincia con “Carneade, chi era costui?”.

Nello stesso capoverso troviamo prima “scale” e poi “scala”. Entrambi gli usi si riferiscono allo stesso elemento architettonico della casa di don Abbondio. Poco più avanti si legge

> Perpetua arriva, un momento prima dell'altra; mentre vuole spinger l’uscio, l’uscio si spalanca di dentro, e sulla soglia compariscono Tonio, Gervaso, Renzo, Lucia, che, trovata la scala, eran venuti giù saltelloni; e, sentendo poi quel terribile scampanìo, correvano in furia, a mettersi in salvo.

Ne deduciamo che l'elemento architettonico *in sé* si chiama *scala*. Ma quando lo percorriamo *saliamo le scale* (o *scendiamo*). Tuttavia il plurale collettivo (come *i pantaloni*) si adopera solo quando la scala è fissa, a gradini (con estensione a quelle mobili dei centri commerciali o della metropolitana). Non sarebbe sorprendente se, nel capoverso precedente, ci fosse *trovate le scale*.

Non è però scorretto dire *salire la scala*.

Se la scala è a pioli o di corda, si adopera normalmente il singolare: *sono salito sulla scala di corda e avevo una paura birbona*.